# Gson bug? PrettyPrinting is ignored if writing to file

Tags: java, gson, outputstream

How to use pretty printing when writing to file?

```
package tests;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter;

public class Try06 {

    public static class V {
        double x, y;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        GsonBuilder gb = new GsonBuilder();

        gb = gb
         .setPrettyPrinting()
         .setVersion(1.0)


         ;

        Gson gson0 = gb.create();

        File file = new File("D:\\test.json");

        System.out.println(gson0.toJson(new V()));

        JsonWriter writer = new JsonWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file)));
        gson0.toJson(new V(), V.class, writer);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();



    }
}
```

Also I noticed, that file is empty if not flushed. Should it flushed when exit?

Comment: Try writer.setIndentSpaces(4);

Comment: Properly behaving classes will flush and close their underlying resources when closed, so `writer.close()` should take care of saving everything out to disk.

Comment: @DmitryTsechoev no such method in writer

Comment: @Suzan Cioc, look at this link (Gson 2.2.4): http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/stream/JsonWriter.html

Comment: @DmitryTsechoev yes there is such method in the sample, but no such method actually; it is also absent in javadoc below on the page you referred.

Comment: Yes, there is a discrepancy in the document and example. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Explicitly setting a non-empty String indent helps:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
JsonWriter writer = new JsonWriter(new FileWriter(fileOut));
writer.setIndent("  "); // <-- without this the file is written without line-breaks and indents
gson.toJson(object, type, writer);
```

Have not had time to check Gson source, probably there's another way to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void newline() throws IOException {
    if (indent == null)
        return;

    out.write("\n");   //--- Your problem here!

    int i = 1;
    for (int size = stackSize; i < size; i++)
        out.write(indent);
}
```

This part of the source of JsonWriter class. As a string delimiter is used '\n'. It is suitable for UNIX systems. But Windows is used for a new line '\r\n'.

How to solve your problem? Look at this:

```
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
dos.writeBytes(gson0.toJson(new V()).replace("\n", "\r\n"));
dos.flush();
dos.close();
```

If you want system independed solution, then replace "\r\n" by this:

```
System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

or by this:

```
System.lineSeparator();
```

Comment: So, what is the principle? Why is it ignore setting in `GsonBuilder`?

Comment: Suzan Cioc, I conducted research and updated my answer.